# CoInitializeEx and CoInitializeSecurity failure

Tags: c++, com, multithreading

I have a C# method that is calling a C++ method.
The C++ method uses WMI, so it calls `CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` and then `CoInitializeSecurity` etc... before making the WMI select.
My Problem, `CoInitializeEX` if failing with code 2147417850 (`RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`)

I tried to create a new STA thread from c# and call the c++ method from this thread (and i disabled the visual studio hosting process), no more error in `CoInitilalize`, but the error happens in `CoInitializeSecurity` (2147417831, `RPC_E_TOO_LATE`).

what is the best solution to correct all this?

Comment: CoInitializeSecurity has already been called. It could happen in some library initialization or obscure places, which you will have to track down. People in SO may be able to help if you tell us what libraries you are using. http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.atl/2004-12/0153.html

Comment: it seems removing both calls solves the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed both calls, problem solved.

Comment: Same for me too!